# Apache RewriteCond RewriteRule combo assistance for HTTPS redirects

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https

Need some help for combining some RewriteRule's and RewriteCond's together and preventing redirect loops.

Case is to force all incoming requests to these patterns, to redirect to https:// with same pattern...

```
http://www.domain.com/admin --> https://www.domain.com/admin
http://www.domain.com/something/wp-login --> https://www.domain.com/something/wp-login
http://www.domain.com/something/wp-admin --> http://www.domain.com/something/wp-admin
http://www.domain.com/something/else/wp-login --> https://www.domain.com/something/else/wp-login
http://www.domain.com/something/else/wp-admin --> https://www.domain.com/something/else/wp-admin
```

But the real trick is that I'd like to accomplish this in the fewest statements. Here's what I have so far, but it's not quite right and creates redirect loops in the /admin cases and fails in the "wp-" cases.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/admin|wp-login|wp-admin) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com$1 [R,L]
```

Much obliged for any pointers here.

Cheers.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

The comment above helped get rid of the redirect loops. I also tried to simplify the preceding RewriteCond in a number of ways but couldn't get anything but the above to work.

For example..why doesn't the below RewriteCond do the same thing only more simply..

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)admin/?$ [NC]
```

Seems to me that should be a true condition for all of the following...

```
http://domain.com/admin
http://domain.com/admin/
http://domain.com/whatever/wp-admin
http://domain.com/whatever/wp-admin/
http://domain.com/whatever/somethingelse/wp-admin
http://domain.com/whatever/somethingelse/wp-admin/
```

But for some reason the wp- urls don't match that condition/pattern.